# Jquery-latest calls an old version

Tags: jquery

I use the `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` to call the latest Jquery. I see this is the v.1.10.2 and not the v.1.11.0 as it should be.
I understand that the v.1.11.0 is a stable version. So why does this happen?

Update: I use the following to load the latest.js and have a fallback as well:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
<\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: You should never, ever use latest as it may break code that you have when jQuery is automatically updated.

Comment: Most likely when 1.11.0 was uploaded the cdn wasn't redirected to the latest version. You could file a bug with jQuery on their github page or just like directly to the 1.11.0 build. In a production environment you probably don't want a floating version anyway just in case breaking changes are introduced in newer versions.

Comment: curious, why aren't you using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js ?

Comment: just to automatically update to the latest version. I use the following format: (see the update on my question)

Comment: The fallback makes sure jQuery loads, but it doesn't prevent a newer version from breaking your site due to deprecations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It seems that the jQuery team intend for it to be immediate:

> "The most commonly requested file is jquery-latest.js, which automatically updates whenever the jQuery Core team releases a new version."

There must be a problem or a mistake has been made. As others have said:

> "Developers should never use jquery-latest.js or jquery-latest.min.js on a production site, it is primarily meant for testing."

http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/14/jquerys-content-delivery-network-you-got-served